# get stacktrace of a python program for debugging

Tags: python, python-3.x, gdb

In order to get the stacktrace of a python program, I am trying to follow [this example](http://grapsus.net/blog/post/Low-level-Python-debugging-with-GDB). In the article, the author invokes the gdb as follows. However, the python version of my environment is `python 3.4.4`. When I type

```
python3.4-dbg  testmyplotlib2.py &
```

The error message is python3.4-dbg: command not found. What's the right way to get stacktrace by using gdb.

[image]

Comment: Not trying to state the obvious here but I think you might not have the debug built installed. (Command not found is the shell warning that something with that name doesn't exist). Here's an article about the setup on Ubuntu https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PyDbgBuilds

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you on? It looks like you need to install python3.4-dbg. If you are on Linux, you will need to enter:

sudo apt-get install python3.4-dbg

Answer (score 0):

GDB is excellent program for debugging, but if printing traceback is the only reason you are installing GDB, do not do it, that is waay overkill. You can just `import traceback` and

1. use `traceback.format_stack()` to get an array of calls that lead to the location in program
2. use `traceback.print_stack()` to print it to command line
3. use `print traceback.format_exc()` to print what lead to the current exceptions (works in `except` clasuse)